# Rummikub: Initial meld with a joker

Tags: rummikub, joker

The following tiles are on the table (these were the initial meld from another player):

10 BLUE, 11 BLUE, 12 BLUE

And I, having not yet made an initial meld, have the following tiles on my board:

7 BLUE, 8 BLUE, 9 BLUE, JOKER, 13 BLUE

I use the first four tiles to make my initial meld.

Questions:

1. Am I allowed to play other tiles in the same round that I played my initial meld?
2. Am I allowed to add my 13 BLUE to the other player's run, take the 10 BLUE to replace the JOKER in my initial meld, and re-use that JOKER, all in the same round?

Answer (score 2):

I've never played this game but reading rules [here](https://tesera.ru/images/items/784463/Rummikub_Rules.pdf) it seems clear enough.  The rules say (emphasis mine)

> In order to place tiles on the table, each player must make an initial
> play of at least 30 points in one or more sets.
>
> These points **must** come from the tiles on the player's rack and **not**
> from tiles already played on the table. A tile is worth its face
> value. A Joker may be used for any tile and its point value is that of
> the tile it represents. The penalty for holding a Joker if another
> player wins the round is 30 points. If a player cannot enter the
> round, or purposely chooses not to, the player must take a tile from
> the pouch and the turn ends.
>
> **After** players have made their initial plays, they can also build on
> other sets on the table with tiles from their racks.

so 1) No you are not allowed to play other tiles the same turn.  The rules are clear that you **must** use your own tiles and **not** other players.  It isn't until **after** all players have made an initial meld or passed you may start building off other players.

The rules for jokers state

> A joker can be retrieved from a set on the table by a player who can replace it during his turn with a tile of the same numerical value and color it represents. The tile used to replace the Joker must come from a *player's rack and not from the table*.

So you can't reuse the joker since the 10 Blue was not in your hand.